# GNU screen is displayed differently on different machines

Tags: ssh, debian, gnu-screen, encoding, kubuntu

I am running

```
$ screen --version
Screen version 4.03.01 (GNU) 28-Jun-15
```

on Debian Jessie via SSH. If I create a `screen` from a machine running Gentoo and then use it from there, Unicode characters (Cyrillic ones, specifically) are always printed correctly.

However, if I create a `screen` from Kubuntu (16.04, upgraded all the way from 15.04), the encoding is broken. Consider this Python script (commands executed without `screen`):

```
$ cat test.py 
print(''.join(chr(c) for c in range(ord('А'), ord('Я') + 1)))
print(''.join(chr(c) for c in range(ord('а'), ord('я') + 1)))
print('Ёё')

$ python3 test.py 
АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
Ёё
```

Now I create a `screen` and try the same from there:

```
$ screen -S test

$ python3 test.py 
�БВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛ����РСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ
абвгдежзийклмноп�����
        ��           �
��������
```

The encoding is also broken if I create a `screen` on Gentoo and then open it from Kubuntu, but in a different way: all non-Latin characters are replaced with '?' signs.

I use Konsole as my terminal both on Gentoo and Kubuntu.

How can I fix this encoding issue?

---

**UPD:** following suggestion by @Jakuje, I added `stty iutf8` to `~/.profile` on the Debian machine. After that, I am getting this:

Gentoo, local terminal:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 55; columns 243; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

$ locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If I execute `stty -a` on the Debian machine via SSH from Gentoo (with or without `screen), the output is exactly the same. Also, Gentoo -SSH-> Debian:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Kubuntu, local terminal:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 172; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr:en_US:es:ru
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Kubuntu -SSH-> Debian:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 172; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

In `stty -a`, there are 2 differences: `discard`/`flush` (line 4) and `-flusho -extproc` (line 8).

The output from within `screen` when I `ssh` into the Debian machine from Kubuntu is the same as without `screen`.

Comment: What is a difference between `stty -a` on both machines? Is there `iutf8`? It looks like your tty does not support UTF8.

Comment: @Jakuje I've updated the post. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, my prompt is using a special arrow character. Displayed correctly over ssh, but I got a `?` when using screen.

On your ssh session, you can start screen with the UTF8 option :
`screen -U`

In this screen session, characters should display normally.

Here the documentation where options are listed : [Screen User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen)

I hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is [known problem](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2477) with planned fix for openssh-7.3 ([draft standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-sgtatham-secsh-iutf8-01)). Before that will be fixed in your distro, there is workaround to run manually (or in some of your login scripts):

```
stty iutf8
```

which will set your tty flags to utf8, as your local shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, this changed nothing. The difference in how characters look is still there. However, `stty -a` now says `iutf8`.

Comment: So how does you `locale` look like. Do you spot some difference? There also should be `utf8`, otherwise python will try to use different encoding.

Comment: I've updated the post with `locale` info. There is `UTF-8` on both machines.

Comment: But different languages. Try to modify you client `ssh`, not to send locale information, as per this [AU question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/781925/ssh-executes-the-command-differently/781952#781952), if it will make a difference.